# Is there any meaning to version names does not starts with *.01

Tags: versions

All Ubuntu versions are *.04 or *.06, or *.10.
Why only 04 or 06 or 10?

Comment: Ubuntu releases are *yy.mm* in format, so 18.04 means the 2018.April release of Ubuntu (and flavors)

Comment: Can you work out when the next release (19.10) is due without looking up the release schedule (ie. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EoanErmine/ReleaseSchedule).

Comment: oct 19 then. Great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu releases are *yy.mm* in format, so 18.04 means the 2018.April release of Ubuntu (and flavors).

Most releases are made in April (.04) and October, though the first release of 2006 occurred in June, so it was 6.06 (2006.June).

The LTS releases are generally the first release of the even year, so Ubuntu 18.04 LTS was a long-term-support release, but you should still check the release notes (*esp. for flavors, eg. Ubuntu Studio 18.04 was not a LTS release, but with PPA added you can still get 3 years of extended support by adding the PPA* - https://ubuntustudio.org/2019/04/ubuntu-studio-18-04-extended-support/)

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

*As added in comments: this makes it very easy to calculate when a release goes EOL.  eg. Ubuntu 14.04 LTS was released in 2014.April with 5 years of supported life, so it's EOL is 2019-April (14+5).04.  The math for non-LTS releases isn't much harder just involving 9 months :)*

Comment: This makes it really easy to know when a release reaches EOL, ie. 14.04 LTS reached it's EOL in (14+9.04 = 19.04) or 2019.April.  17.10 reached it's EOL in 17.(10+9) = 2018.July (okay that involves a subtraction but it's still easy!)  LTS releases have 5 years of support (3 for flavors), normal releases have 9 months.

Comment: So many useful info.

Comment: I made an error in my comment typing/calculation, 14.04=(14+5year).04 = 19.04 , 17.(10+9month)=2018.July .. sorry.